# Android Editext - Enter negative number numberDecimal|numberSigned

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, negative-number, android-inputtype

I have an edittext that I want to accept positive and negative numbers.

It works phone on my phone, the keyboard shows the "-" sign, however it doesn't work on some phone whereas the "-" doesn't show up on their keyboard. See the attached images. How to fix it so that it works on all Android phones. I set the edittext to android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" The first image is on my phone whereas the 2nd image shows the user's phone and he's having problem entering the "-" sign. He uses Android version 5.0.1.
[image]

[image]

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/number"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I can see the '-' on both images. Probably on the lower one you need to hold the button for it though.

Comment: yah, it works. They hold on the key and it worked. thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'll move my comment to the answer if you don't mind, so you can accept the answer if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment to the answer:

> I can see the `-` on both images. Probably on the lower one you need to hold the button for it though.

It worked, holding the button selects the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

On the second keyboard the `-` can be found as option on the `)` key. So you did everything right. Setting `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"` should suffice. But eventually you might find keyboards not handling these types correctly. But then there's nothing you could do about it anyway.